# RotateFlip bug when using a 1Bpp image. C# What can I do?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to rotate a Bitmap with 1Bpp PixelIndex but I've found that it's bugged. When you try to do some of the rotations, a black line will appear on the left side of the image. Doing some research I found that is a bug but probably won't be fixed.

I've tried another way to rotate the Bitmap (I include the code):

```
Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(lBitmap.Width, lBitmap.Height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
g.TranslateTransform((float)lBitmap.Width / 2, (float)lBitmap.Height / 2);
                        g.RotateTransform(180);
                        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)lBitmap.Width / 2, -(float)lBitmap.Height / 2);
                        g.DrawImage(lBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
                        mIsRotated = true;
```

But my problem here is that the image loses definition when rotated 180º.

Is there any other way to rotate?

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: These are common interpolation artifacts, there's no obvious reason why they occur from the snippet.  You'll need to make your bitmap file available on a file sharing service to get help.

Comment: Here you can download the image I'm working with: http://www.4shared.com/file/CCXvYNqq/2e_lemon.html

Comment: 1 bpp will only give you a 2 color palette (background and foreground) leaving nothing for interpolation (though a 90, 180 and 270 degree rotation or flips doesn't require interpolation at all). Try to convert the image to a full RGB and then rotate, if that is an option.

Comment: I have to work with a 1Bpp due to the size of the image.

Comment: Can you add an original code which gave you a black line?

Comment: The black line appears when using the Bitmap.RotateFlipType.Rotate"XX"Flip"XX". I don't remember which one, but think it was "Rotate270FlipNone". 
Anyway, I just found a solution. I'll post it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone ends here having the same problem, I found a solution. I couldn't use the Bitmap.RotateFlip because it generated a black line, so I tried with that code above. With 180º my images lost some definition, but using -180º solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while extracting monochrome bitmaps from icons and cursors.

Flipping is not rotating. This would be better:

```
Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(lBitmap.Width, lBitmap.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
g.TranslateTransform((float)lBitmap.Width / 2, (float)lBitmap.Height / 2);
// Mirror instead of rotate
g.ScaleTransform(1,-1);
g.TranslateTransform(-(float)lBitmap.Width / 2, -(float)lBitmap.Height / 2);
g.DrawImage(lBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
mIsRotated = true;
```

However the resulting bitmap will not be 1bpp

This function flips a monochrome bitmap in-place taking advantage of the fact that rows are 32-bit aligned:

```
/// <summary>
/// Vertically flips a monochrome bitmap in-place
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bmp">Monochrome bitmap to flip</param>
public static void RotateNoneFlipYMono(Bitmap bmp)
{
    if (bmp == null || bmp.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
        throw new InvalidValueException();

    var height = bmp.Height;
    var width = bmp.Width;
    // width in dwords
    var stride = (width + 31) >> 5;
    // total image size
    var size = stride * height;
    // alloc storage for pixels
    var bytes = new int[size];

    // get image pixels
    var rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);            
    var bd = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);            
    Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, bytes, 0, size);

    // flip by swapping dwords
    int halfSize = size >> 1;
    for (int y1 = 0, y2 = size - stride; y1 < halfSize; y1 += stride, y2 -= stride)
    {
        int end = y1 + stride;
        for (int x1 = y1, x2 = y2; x1 < end; x1++, x2++)
        {
            bytes[x1] ^= bytes[x2];
            bytes[x2] ^= bytes[x1];
            bytes[x1] ^= bytes[x2];
        }
    }

    // copy pixels back
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, bd.Scan0, size);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bd);
}
```